# Dead key sequence for quotes works oddly in Eclipse in MacOS X

Tags: macos, mac, eclipse, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

I'm using an US-International Keyboard in MacOS.

The normal behavior for dead keys in every application is, for example, if I press the key sequence <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> it understands that the comma doesn't carry an accent as would a vowel, so both the apostrophe and the comma get entered as in a normal US keyboard.

But in eclipse, the dead key sequence seems to *eat* the comma, which never appears. entering the comma (or any other character that doesn't take an accent) does terminate the dead key sequence, but doesn't get printed, so I have to terminate the quotes with a space and then enter the following character.

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of dead key sequence for single-quote characters with the "US-International Keyboard" on the Mac OS X Mavericks. I changed the keyboard in the input sources to to the regular "US keyboard" and it now works fine. Thank you @Petruza